# How to draw two lines of text on Android softkeyboard keys?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way to draw two lines of text on Android SoftKeyboard without images? I mean something like that

```
Caps
Lock
```

on a single key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried **KeyboardView**'s onDraw() method?  There you can paint alternate characters on a key.  Something like this that I have used in my own code:

```
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        paint.setTextSize(23);
        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for(Key key: keys) {
            String upperLetter = bindingsMap.get(key.label.toString());
            canvas.drawText(upperLetter, key.x + (key.width/2)+14, key.y + 21, paint);                      
        }
    }
```